# Unable to install Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, dell-inspiron

I'm using Dell Inspiron 1420 with Windows Vista Home premium. 2 weeks back installed Windows7 as dual boot on to my laptop. I installed it in a new way as my CD/DVD drive is not working. I extracted the Windows7 iso file into a folder and then double clicked on the setup file. The a series of dialogue boxes which pop up for normal installation appeared and done, I got Windows7 dual booted onto my laptop.

Now I'm trying to install Windows XP in the same way, as I don't want to use Vista due to compatibility reasons. But when I double click the setup file in the extracted iso, all the options except **Install Win XP** are working. I tried many times but the option is disabled. Please help me with this. I'm badly in need of XP. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows 7 has XP mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode), why not use that instead of reinstalling XP?

Comment: I forgot about that.

Comment: Works well, but you need enough memory installed for it to run well, 2gb.

Comment: With 3GB I can run 2 VM's while the dev environment is open too. It's well worth the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this guide](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1114826.htm) for installing XP after Windows 7 is already installed.

It means creating a second partition on your hard-drive to hold XP.